# UITabBarController unresponsive for touches

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbarcontroller

So, I have this view hierarchy in my app:

```
UIWindow
UIViewController
UITabBarController -> 4 UINavigationController
```

I know that a UITabBarController is designed to be the topmost view in an app, however this isn't possible in my case. However, the problem that I have is that ~20 of the lower pixels aren't responsive for touches so that the UITabBarController doesn't trigger the tab changes correctly. This happens on an actual device (iPad and iPhone 3G).

My question is, are there any obvious reasons why this could happen? I add the UITabBarController like this as subview to my UIViewController view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view]; // Controller is the UITabBarController
}
```

I didn't set the UITabBarController's delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITabBarController should never be embedded in a UIViewController because, as it descends from UIViewController, it already is one; just with extra flair. Currently the root UIViewController is intercepting all of your touch events.

Make the UITabBarController's view the subview of your UIWindow in the app delegate.

Comment: Well yeah, like I said, I'm aware of this but it really isn't possible. But I can assure you that the UIViewController doesn't intercept the touches.

Comment: Its not possible because I need to change the content of the UIViewController depending on its orientation at runtime. Even worse, I want this nice animation thing to display the rotation change and then change the content in the second half of the animation (bad two staged animation). This is not possible with an UIWindow.

Comment: Unless you're switching to some alternative view when the device is rotated horizontally I don't see why you can't handle rotation with the UITabBarController since it inherits all of that functionality from UIViewController.

Comment: @CrystalSkull Like I wrote, I switch the complete UI during the rotation. There is one case were just another normal UIView subclass is added and two cases were another UIViewController subclass view gets added. Its not really impossible but really dirty and also not really the way I want to go.

Comment: Okay, I did it a little bit different without two staged animation, three subclasses and some dirty anmiation stuff spread around four files. But hey, at least it works ^^